MongoDB $graphLookup for finding hierarchy of related documents in a collection
I am trying to find hierarchy of documents (Aggregation) from a collection in MongoDB using $graphLookup with keys partOf and contains which are of Object datatype that store array of categories and the _id field inside.
Input collection sample (relationships_collection):
// Doc 1:

{
  "_id": "gotham_hotel",
  "category": "hotel",
  "partOf": {
    "street": [
      "kings_street_street"
    ]
  }
}

// Doc 2:

{
  "_id": "kings_street_street",
  "category": "street",
  "partOf": {
    "pincode": [
      "m24ah_pincode"
    ]
  }
}

// Doc 3:

{
  "_id": "m24ah_pincode",
  "category": "pincode",
  "partOf": {
    "city": [
      "manchester_city"
    ]
  }
}

// Doc 4:

{
  "_id": "manchester_city",
  "category": "city",
  "partOf": {
    "country": [
      "england_country"
    ]
  }
}

// Doc 5:

{
  "_id": "england_country",
  "category": "country",
  "partOf": {
    "continent": [
      "europe_continent"
    ]
  }
}

// Doc 6:

{
  "_id": "europe_continent",
  "category": "continent",
  "partOf": {
    "region": [
      "north_region"
    ]
  }
}

// Doc 7 (Not partOf any other document _id. Dead End):

{
  "_id": "north_region",
  "category": "region",
  "contains": {
    "continent": [
      "europe_continent",
      "antarctica_continent"
    ]
  }
}

Expected Output of Aggregation:
// Fetch complete hierarchy of gotham_hotel or any other document:

{
  "_id": "gotham_hotel",
  "category": "hotel",
  "partOf": {
    "street": [
      {
        "_id": "kings_street_street",
        "category": "street",
        "partOf": {
          "pincode": [
            {
              "_id": "m24ah_pincode",
              "category": "pincode",
              "partOf": {
                "city":  [
                  {
                    "_id": "manchester_city",
                    "category": "city",
                    "partOf": {
                      "country": [
                        {
                          "_id": "england_country",
                          "category": "country",
                          "partOf": {
                            "continent": [
                              {
                                "_id": "europe_continent",
                                "category": "continent",
                                "partOf": {
                                  "region": [
                                    {
                                      "_id": "north_region",
                                      "category": "region",
                                      "contains": {
                                        "continent": [
                                          "europe_continent",
                                          "antarctica_continent"
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

I tried using the following aggregation query, but not able to get the desired output.
[
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "gotham_hotel"
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "relationships_collection",
      startWith: "$partOf.street",
      connectFromField: "partOf.street",
      connectToField: "_id",
      depthField: "depth",
      as: "partOfHierarchy"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "partOf": {
        "street": {
          "$setUnion": [
            {
              "$ifNull": [
                "$partOf.steet",
                []
              ]
            },
            {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$partOfHierarchy.partOf.street",
                "initialValue": [],
                "in": {
                  "$setUnion": [
                    "$$value",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "pincode": {
          "$setUnion": [
            {
              $ifNull: [
                "$partOf.pincode",
                []
              ]
            },
            {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$partOfHierarchy.partOf.pincode",
                "initialValue": [],
                "in": {
                  "$setUnion": [
                    "$$value",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

How can I achieve the desired output using aggregation query?

dynamic field names is always a pain. not sure if this one is possible. https://mongoplayground.net/p/lnoMz8Sh3xp not a solution, just to show how things become bit more easy when field names are static

static field names could be a secondary option. dynamic field names schema is a bit easier to store and understand. Let's see if anyone can come up with a solution.

Dynamic field names, dynamic nesting levels, inconsistent parent-child modelling... are all anti-patterns. Advice from joe and cmgchess make sense and you should follow them to refactor your schema

You won't get precisely that output from MongoDB.
However, in the case of a simple linked list like this, you can get an array that would be trivially converted to that hierarchy on the client side.
First, a schema change to simplify the lookup.  Since each id is already tagged with its type, there may not be a need to specify the type explicitly, but if there is, adding that as a sibling field makes this easier.  Something like:
      "partOf": [
        {
          "type": "street",
          "id": "kings_street_street"
        }

This simplifies the graphLookup stage because the field name is then consistent for all documents:
  {"$graphLookup": {
      "from": "relationships_collection",
      "startWith": "$partOf.id",
      "connectFromField": "partOf.id",
      "connectToField": "_id",
      "as": "LookedUp",
      "depthField": "depth"
  }}

This returns the discovered documents in an unsorted array, but with depthField, this are easily sorted:
{"$addFields": {
      "LookedUp": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$LookedUp",
          "sortBy": {"depth": 1}
        }
      }
}}

The resulting array contains the hierarchy, on client side you can iterate the array to nest each element in the one before it.
Example: Playground

Thanks. Let me try out this approach after tweaking the schema.

Was able to fetch the complete hierarchy with the schema change (by adding the sibling field as suggested). This is helpful. Thank you @Joe.

Allow me to reiterate: Dynamic field names, dynamic nesting levels, inconsistent parent-child modelling... are all anti-patterns. Please seriously consider the invaluable advice from @joe and @cmgchess to refactor your schema.
Nevertheless, for your current scenario, if we only consider the "tree" starting from gotham_hotel, we may get close to the desired structure by doing 3 things:

Ignore the north_region node. It doesn't follow the rule of being a child node that have a partOf field. Instead, it becomes a parent node with the contains field. Fortunately it is already the leave node and we do not need it to recursively find further node anymore, at least in the given example
create a view to "flatten" your current documents to have static field name for $graphLookup, which is suggested by @joe
With the created view in step #2, apply the concept in this answer to reform the recursive structure.

Regarding step #2, we use below command to create a view with $objectToArray to standardize the field name for $graphLookup
db.createView(
  "relationshipView",
  "relationships",
  [
    {
      $set: {
        partOf: {$first: { $objectToArray: '$partOf' }}
      }
    }
  ]
)

So a sample document from relationshipView will look like this:
{
      "_id": "gotham_hotel",
      "category": "hotel",
      "partOf": {
        "k": "street",
        "v": [
          "kings_street_street"
        ]
      }
    }

We can use partOf.v to look up _id
Next in step #3, we shamelessly apply the linked answer's concept to reconstruct the tree. This requires a minor modification, since the original question is a parent-to-child lookup, while here is a child-to-parent lookup. I don't think I can give a better explanation than the original answer. Please read the explanation there and vote it up if it helped you to learn something.
{
    $set: {
      partOf: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$partOf",
          initialValue: {
            level: -1,
            presentPartOf: [],
            prevPartOf: []
          },
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                prev: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$value.level",
                        "$$this.level"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.prevPartOf",
                    "$$value.presentPartOf"
                  ]
                },
                current: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$value.level",
                        "$$this.level"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.presentPartOf",
                    []
                  ]
                }
              },
              in: {
                level: "$$this.level",
                prevPartOf: "$$prev",
                presentPartOf: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$current",
                    [
                      {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$this",
                          {
                            partOf: {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$$prev",
                                as: "e",
                                cond: {
                                  $in: [
                                    "$$e._id",
                                    "$$this.partOf.v"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "partOf": "$partOf.presentPartOf"
    }
  }

Full code in Mongo Playground

Again, you are reminded about the caveats of the above anti-patterns and the difficulty of processing such a dynamically nesting structure. Refactor the schema if possible.

Nice use of reduce.
